# Implementing a JMenu with actionPerformed using TextAction

Tags: java, swing, awt, jmenu

I have a Java Swing interface with multiple `JTextArea`'s and I am implementing an "Edit" menu with various different functions like "Find", "Copy", "Paste", etc. When I click on the `JMenuItem` I need to know which `JTextArea` had the focus which is achievable through a `TextAction` (I haven't gone down the route of a `FocusListener` and keeping track of what last had the focus):

```
JMenuItem miFind = new JMenuItem(new EditHandler("Find"));

class EditHandler extends TextAction {
  private String s = null;

  public EditHandler(String vs) {
    super(vs);
    s = vs;
  }

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JTextComponent c = getFocusedComponent();
    if (s.equals("Find")) {
      showFindDialog(c);
    }
  }
}
```

This works well and good but I want to be able to disable the "Find" `JMenuItem` under certain contexts (i.e. if the specific `JTextArea` is disabled or is empty. I can implement an `ActionListener` on a `JMenu` but I can't use `getFocusedComponent()` to identify what `JTextArea` has the focus.

According to the Java docs the `JMenu` constructor takes an `Action` (like a `JMenuItem`) and I have tried the following:

```
mEdit = new JMenu(new EditHandler("Edit"));
```

However, although the constructor fires, the `actionPerformed()` event isn't firing within my `EditHandler` for the `JMenu`. If I can get it to fire then I was planning to either enable or disable my "Find" `JMenuItem`.

Comment: Related in the sense that it applies an `AbstractAction` to a `JMenuItem` or have I missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way for you is using of actions map of the text component to place the corresponding action. In this case you can disable it for some text components.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  JTextComponent c = getFocusedComponent();
  if (s.equals("Find")) {
    Action a = c.getActionMap().get("Find");
    if (a.isEnabled()) {
      // generate new event to modify the source (menu item -> text component)
      ActionEvent ae = new ActionEvent(c, e.getID(), e.getCommand());
      a.actionPerformed(ae);
    }
  }
}
```

For each your text component you must provide an action and register it using the action map of the component.

```
public class UniversalFindAction extends AbstractAction {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    JTextComponent c = (JTextComponent) ae.getSource();
    showFindDialog(c);
  }
}

// registering of action
JTextComponent comp = new JTextArea();
comp.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK), "Find");
comp.getActionMap().put("Find", new UniversalFindAction());
```

Comment: I am trying to grey out the actual `JMenuItem` in the `JMenu` as opposed to just disabling the action if the `JTextArea` is empty. Is this possible with the above approach?

Comment: It's another problem. To solve it you can install global focus listener. Use Toolkig.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(...) method. So each time when you get focus ganed event for a JTextComponent you can check whether it's empty or not.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have used a Global Focus Listener which keeps track of which `JTextArea` was last to be focused which removes the use of my `TextAction`. I will mark this as correct and provide my solution below.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @sergiy-medvynskyy I have implemented a Global Focus Listener to keep track of the last `JTextArea` to be focused:

```
KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addPropertyChangeListener("permanentFocusOwner", new PropertyChangeListener() {
  @Override
  public void propertyChange(final PropertyChangeEvent e) {
    if (e.getNewValue() instanceof JTextArea) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          tFocused = (JTextArea)e.getNewValue();
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

I then check the `tFocused` object using a `MenuListener` on my `JMenu` to verify what `JTextArea` currently has the focus. I can then call `setEnabled()` on my respective `JMenuItem`'s depending on the context.